# Styled-components in React.js - props doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I've tried everything. At least, for a while, I can't find any new possible solution for my problem. There is a possibility that I don't understand something, because I'm at the beginning of my adventure with React.js.

To the point:

I want to create a component-header with a background image. In the parent component, I put an image URL as a prop and try to use it in the child component as a `background-image: URL()`. And it, of course, doesn't work. Also, I've tried to set a colour, and it also doesn't work.

Here is my parent component:

```
import Hero from '../Hero';
import image from './cat.jpg'

function Main() {
    
    return <div>
        <Hero title="Only fluff photos" image={image} color="#f0f"/>
    </div>
};
```

and here is my child component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledHeader = styled.header`
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 432px;
    background-image: url(${(props) => props.image});
    background-color: ${props => props.color ? props.color : "#ff0"};
`

function Hero(props) {
    
    return <StyledHeader>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <img src={props.image} alt="test cat" />
    </StyledHeader>
};
```

What I've tried:

1. Put the same URL into img tag as a `src` - it works
2. Import an img directly in child component and us `{image}` - it works
3. Use `require()` - it doesn't work
4. Use `url(~{props.image})` - it doesn't work
5. Use different forms of props when styling my `StyledHeader` - it doesn't work
6. Put an image into a folder that has exactly the same path for both components - it doesn't work.

Of course, all of points from 3 to 6 doesn't work, because none of props works. But I've found that later.

styled-components gives an example of props usage:

```
background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
```

It doesn't help me :(

Thanks in advance for any help! I have no idea what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work because you have to give the Styled header the prop as followed

```
const StyledHeader = styled.header`
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 432px;
background-image: url(${(props) => props.image});
background-color: ${props => props.color ? props.color : "#ff0"};
`

function Hero(props) {
  return <StyledHeader image={props.image} color={"value"} {...otherProps}>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <img src={props.image} alt="test cat" />
  </StyledHeader>
};
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand! It WORKS!

Comment: Coool, Thanks. @Slavian